# How can I get Opencv cv::Mat hsv pixels value?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, hsv

I have a frame which is taken from video:

```
VideoCapture cap(videoPath);
Mat frame;
cap >> frame;
```

Frame have target which is blue. So I use Hsv:

```
Mat blue_hsv;
cvtColor(frame, blue_hsv, cv::COLOR_RGB2HSV);
inRange(blue_hsv, cv::Scalar(0, 50, 50), cv::Scalar(30, 255, 255), blue_hsv);
```

HSV İmage

[image]

Next, I want to get value of pixels. Is pixel white or black. But it didn't work:

```
for (int i = 0; i<blue_hsv.rows; i++)
 {
    for (int j = 0; j<blue_hsv.cols; j++)
    {
        Vec3b& hsv = blue_hsv.at<Vec3b>(i, j);

        cout << hsv[0] << ",";
        cout << hsv[1] << ",";
        cout << hsv[2] << endl;
    }
}
```

I take the "abord()" error. My main purpose is bringing the figure straight with using Pixels. So what can I do for it? How can reach value of hsv pixels?

Comment: delete this line: `inRange(blue_hsv, cv::Scalar(0, 50, 50), cv::Scalar(30, 255, 255), blue_hsv);` or put it before this line your loop.

Comment: The last parameter of inRange is the destination of the binary image, in this case it is the same, so you can not get the hsv since you have overwritten it with the binary image.